# Where does the "One of us! One of us!" chant originate?

Tags: reference, the-big-bang-theory, origin, south-park

I've seen the chant "One of us! One of us!" parodied in both South Park and Big Bang Theory.

Where does it come from?
Is "Gibble Gobble Gibble Gobble" (added by South Park) part of the original chant?

Comment: Searching "One of us! One of us!" on Google returned *Freaks* as the **first** hit.

Comment: Your point? I googled for something, couldn't find it, posted here. What should I have done differently?

Comment: I just Googled the chant *exactly as you posted it*, and wondered why you didn't. That's all. If you had searched "One of us! One of us!" like you asked, it's the first returned hit. (I only brought it up vis-à-vis the old adage "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime." It's meant to help you in the future- to improve your Goole-Fu.)

Comment: @MeatTrademark well now *this post* is the first returned hit...

Comment: Oh, internet...

Comment: simpsons did it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y_KNYNzN6A they referred everything i guess

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Tod Browning's controversial cult horror film [Freaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freaks_(1932_film)) from 1932.

> The central story is of this conniving trapeze artist Cleopatra, who seduces and marries sideshow midget Hans after learning of his large inheritance. At their wedding reception, the other "freaks" announce that they accept Cleopatra in spite of her being a "normal" outsider; they hold an initiation ceremony in which they pass a massive goblet of wine around the table while chanting, **"We accept her, we accept her. One of us, one of us. Gooble-gobble, gooble-gobble."**

Cleopatra tries to poison Hans, and when the circus "freaks" find out,

> they take their revenge by turning her into a duck woman - into "one of them".

The dinner scene was referenced in [many other](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Freaks_(1932_film)&oldid=924986897#Legacy) films and shows. Here it is:

Answer (score 2):

It originated in the move Freaks (1932), but was actually popularized by The Ramones in the song 'Pinhead'.

Comment: *How* was it popularized by the song? This seems like just another reference, which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score -10):

No, it doesn't come from that movie. Most people today have never seen it. It comes from I, Robot 2004.
http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=I+robot+one+of+us&view=detail&&mid=037CC7793439FFC7C8DE037CC7793439FFC7C8DE

Comment: Not only should we give some credit to the creators of these shows and their pop culture knowledge, but please also note that the [South Park episode in question aired in 2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butters'_Very_Own_Episode).

Comment: Wrong. It's in *Toy Story*, too... Which came out a decade earlier. Clearly this is not the first instance.